# Одинаковый шрифт в формулах и тексте

Tags: latex

Верстка происходит в программе TeXstudio, установлен PSCyr, TimesNewRoman определяю следующей командой `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ftm}`. Данная команда выполняется для всего текста, кроме формул. Как использовать TimesNewRoman внутри окружения формул?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ftm}
\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{OT1}{\rmdefault}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{bold}{OT1}{\rmdefault}{b}{n}

\begin{document}

Какой-то текст на русском языке

$\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Да, на первый взгляд эти шрифты выглядят вполне нормально. Немного настораживает, что автор за исходный использовал TeXGyre Terms (это который реализует гарнитуру Times - весьма низкокачественные шрифты по сравнению с PSCyr, и уже давно без кириллицы). Но автор утверждает, что довольно существенно их подправил, поэтому, наверное можно применять и их.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько мне известно, проблема в том, что в наборе *PSCyr* нет математических шрифтов. Соответственно, есть два варианта. 1. Использовать для текста гарнитуру *Литературная* (она же *Quant Antiqua*), тогда к ней по стилю подойдет "математика" из стандартного *Computer Modern*. 2. Если все же очень нужно использовать Times как основной, то тогда нужно дополнительно установить шрифты *MathTime Pro*. И можно будет подключить эти шрифты следующими командами:

```
% шрифты PSCyr:
\usepackage {pscyr} 
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ftm} 

% шрифты MTPro
\usepackage[subscriptcorrection,slantedGreek,nofontinfo]{mtpro}  
\usepackage[mtphrb]{mtpams}  
\usepackage[mtpcal]{mtpb}
```

Инструкция по установке в MikTeX шрифтов MTPro от **karl_karlsson** (ее также можно найти в интернетах):

## Установка шрифтов mtpro в MikTeX 2.9

1. Copy the files from the packages archives
2. Start -> Programs -> MiKTeX 2.9 -> Settings -> Refresh FNDB
3. Command Prompt

   > initexmf --edit-config-file dvips

   ```
   p +mtpro.map
   p +mtproa.map
   p +mtprob.map
   ```

   > initexmf --edit-config-file pdftex

   ```
   map +mtpro.map
   map +mtproa.map
   map +mtprob.map
   ```

   > initexmf --edit-config-file updmap

   ```
   Map mtpro.map
   Map mtproa.map
   Map mtprob.map
   ```
4. Command Prompt

   > updmap

Comment: Опыт использования LaTeX нулевой.
 ```\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ftm}``` я вызвал без подгрузки пакета PSCyr, просто голый вызов, это большая ошибка? Я так понимаю LaTeX просто нашел эту команду и ввиду отсутствия конфликта имен правильно вызвал шрифт.
**PSCyr** ставил по гайду, есть ли такой для **MathTimePro**?

Comment: @ЭрдэниЦырендоржиев, нет, здесь можно и без явного указания пакета. Вроде бы, MTPro ставится так же, как и PSCyr. В том смысле, что в пакете все уже разложено по нужным подкаталогам - нужно только скопировать в главное дерево каталогов теха, а потом нужно добавить как и PSCyr в те же файлы конфигурации и прогнать команды initexmf и updmap. Но самое главное, это найти эти шрифты, ибо они немного коммерческие? как я понимаю, и их периодически чистят из свободного доступа... Краткую инструкцию по установке к MikTeX я добавлю в ответ (в принципе, для TeXLive процедура должна быть похожа).

Comment: Узнал из англоязычного stackoverflow еще один способ, без установок доп пакетов, оформил как ответ